# How to form the transactionObject in a metamask enforced async call?

Tags: web3js, transactions, synchronization, contract-invocation, metamask

Normally, for a contract call (i.e. something that does not update ethereum), I would simply do: `var something = myContractObject.getSomething()`.

I've just started using `metamask`, and unfortunately, that breaks with the complaint that such calls are not asynchronous. Why? They've always returned synchronously for me! Is that because I've only used `testrpc` or a private network?

Anyway, if I must make such calls async', since I make many such calls, rather than write callbacks for every one of them, I'm trying to write a function to handle it all for me. Something like this:

```
callHandler (_transactionObject) {
  let value = undefined
  this.web3.eth.call( _transactionObject, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return undefined
    } else {
      return result
    }
  })
}
```

That relies on the parameter `_transactionObject`. I've written a little function that tries forming that:

```
getTransactionObject ( _data ) {
  const account = this.account
  return { from: account, data: _data }
}
```

And here's how I call that function:

```
const data = myContractObject.getSomething.getData()
var transactionObject = getTransactionObject(data)
```

Then I simply try and replicate `var something = myContractObject.getSomething()`, by calling `callHandler`, i.e. `var something = callHandler(transactionObject)`.

...but that's not working; it seems that `myContractObject.getSomething.getData()` (which I got from here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods), is not returning the right call data for the `transactionObject`. In which case, I'm a bit stuck - how do I get the call data I need and form the correct `transactionObject`?

ps. I realise there are other problems with that code, not least `var something = callHandler(transactionObject)` is not async', so the assignment to `something` needs wrapping in some async' handler....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `const data = myContractObject.getSomething.getData()` to create a `transactionObject`, I solved this by just passing in `myContractObject.getSomething` to `callHandler`, along with a callback function. Something like this:

```
callHandler( myContractObject.getSomething, callbackFunction )
```

And `callHandler` looks something like this:

```
callHandler (_func, _cb ) {
_func( function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log("got result " + result)
    _cb(result)
  }
})
```

}

...works nicely :)